# Open a webpage (HTML) from Windows Form

Tags: c#, html, web

I have a webpage(HTML). I want to open this web page (HTML) from windows form. I want to make sure that this page loads once its opened from Windows From only. Please note that user should not be able type the URL in browser and load.

Comment: `Please note that user should not be able type the URL in browser and load.` Why not? Once you load the web page in the browser, what stops then copying the URL, opening a new tab and opening it there?

Comment: Because I want to show the webpage to user once he is authorized using my Windows Form. (Authentication is done locally inside windows form).

Comment: Is it possible that I send some "token" from my Windows form and authenticate those token in webform? If that is authenticated, web page should load.

Comment: What stops me copying that URL and loading it in a separate tab?

Comment: Its security requiremnt

Comment: It has two step security. Once user is authenticated using first step, only then he / she should be able to see main log in form.

Comment: `Its security requiremnt` That it is a requirement doesn't magically make it possible. What stops me copying that URL and loading it in a separate tab? Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: `It has two step security. Once user is authenticated using first step, only then he / she should be able to see main log in form.` Can you talk us through _why_ you want to do it this way? _Note 'it is a requirement' is not an answer._

Answer (score -1):

Your question gives no indication of what you have tried but the standard way of embedding browser functionality in a windows form application is via a webview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview